# Parsing Json to zoned date time

Tags: java, jackson

Im reciving following json time format

```
"TimeEnd": "2017-05-24 09:52:51+02:00"
```

my dto is as follows:

```
 @JsonProperty("TimeEnd")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonZonedDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private ZonedDateTime timeEnd;
```

I wrote following deserializer

```
public class JsonZonedDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<ZonedDateTime> {


    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(jp.getText());
    }
}
```

but im getting:

Text '2017-05-24 09:52:51+02:00' could not be parsed at index 10

I have tried multiple solutions but none of them seems to work...

Answer (score 2):

You can use just:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX");
return ZonedDateTime.parse(jp.getText(), dateTimeFormatter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be trying to parse it as a `ZonedDateTime`, as it really *doesn't* have a time zone - it has a UTC offset. `OffsetDateTime` is more appropriate here. It's worth differentiating between the two types - you *can* create a `ZonedDateTime` with a time zone that's just a fixed UTC offset, but you should understand that that's not the same as a "regular" time zone. If you only ever have offsets at a single instant, `OffsetDateTime` is better.

Now because your input value doesn't have the "T" required by the standard pattern, you'll need to use a custom pattern, but that's pretty easy:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXXXX", Locale.ROOT);
        String text = "2017-05-24 09:52:51+02:00";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }       
}
```

Comment: @filemonczyk: Not really sure what you mean, but the code I provided works on my machine, and the number of Xs was deliberate as per the documentation: "Five letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, with a colon, such as '+01:30:15'"